# Time complexity of dictionary lookup in Python

Tags: python

I have a function that builds substrings given a string recursively. Could anyone please tell me what's the complexity of this? I'm guessing it's O(2**n), because given an input of n, there can be 2**n substrings, but i'm not 100% sure.

Here's the code:

```
def build_substrings(string):
    """ Returns all subsets that can be formed with letters in string. """
    result = []
    if len(string) == 1:
        result.append(string)
    else:
        for substring in build_substrings(string[:-1]):
            result.append(substring)
            substring = substring + string[-1]
            result.append(substring)
        result.append(string[-1])
    return result
```

I actually have on more question that i think doesn't deserve a new topic. I was wondering what's the complexity of searching a key in a dictionary in Python(if item in dictionary)?
Thank you alot for your help!

Comment: you need to find all the possible substrings of a given string?

Comment: Key lookup in dict should be `O(1)`. Do you mean `2**n` by `2*n`? Also, I'd recommend timing your function to answer your question.

Comment: you are making 2**n-1 strings. You also need to take care of the special case for string = "". Gives me a pretty nasty traceback

Comment: Appending one string to another may not be a constant-time operation, which would affect the time complexity.

Comment: No, I think you read my question wrong. I know how to find the substrings, i just don't know the time complexity of this. 
I'll try to time my function and see how much it helps me. Oh and yes, i meant 2**n instead of 2*n, i'm sorry.
Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If N is the length of string.Number of substring of length >=1<=N is (N * N+1)/2.

So time Complexity would be O(N**2)

The python dict is a hashmap, its worst case is therefore O(n) if the hash function is bad and results in a lot of collisions. However that is a very rare case where every item added has the same hash and so is added to the same chain which for a major Python implementation would be extremely unlikely. The average time complexity is of course O(1).

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain the logic behind (N * N+1)/2.
Let's say i have a string of lenght 5. the number of substrings should be 2**n = 32. Your equation gives the output 15 for a string of lenght 5. Am i missing something ?

Comment: @geekkid let say string = 'abcde' substring = ['a','b','c','d','e','ab','bc',cd','de','abc','bcd','cde','abcd','bcde','abcde']

Comment: But whatabout "ae", "ad" and so on ? I might be wrong with a subset definition maybe ? the output with "abc" should be ['a', 'ac', 'ab', 'abc', 'b', 'bc', 'c'], i'm not exactly sure how this is called. permutations ?

Answer (score 3):

First, here are two more ways to write your function.

```
# this one's about the same speed
import itertools
def build_substrings_2(s):
    return [''.join(r) for r in itertools.product(*(['',ch] for ch in s))]

# this one's about 4 times faster
def build_substrings_3(s):
    res = [""]
    for ch in s:
        res += [r+ch for r in res]
    return res
```

Here's how you can measure the speed:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import izip
import timeit

xs = range(3, 25)
fns = ['build_substrings_1', 'build_substrings_2', 'build_substrings_3']
res = [(fn, []) for fn in fns]
for i,s in ((chars,"a"*chars) for chars in xs):
    ts  = [
        timeit.Timer(
            '{}({})'.format(fn, repr(s)),
            'from __main__ import {}'.format(fn)
        )
        for fn in fns
    ]
    for t,r in izip(ts, res):
        r[1].append(min(t.repeat(number=10)))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, yscale='log')
for label,dat in res:
    ax.plot(xs, dat, label=label)
legend = plt.legend(loc='upper left')
```

[image]

(y axis is log of runtime in seconds, x axis is length of input string in characters)

and here's how you find the best polynomial fit:

```
import numpy

data = [numpy.log10(r[1]) for r in res]       # take log of data
best = [numpy.polyfit(xs[5:], dat[5:], 1) for dat in data]   # find best-fit line
big_o = [10**(b[0]) for b in best]         # convert slope back to power
```

(thanks to DSM for this simplified method!)

which results in

```
[2.0099844256336676, 2.0731239717002787, 2.0204035253442099]
```

... your function is about O(n**2.00998)

Comment: If you're just doing a polynomial fit (on the log of the data), wouldn't `numpy.polyfit` be much simpler?

Comment: @DSM: thank you, I wasn't aware of that function. It does look simpler.